# I delete appcompat v7

Tags: android, android-activity

I cleaned appcompat v7 file the cleaning delete R.java then I delete the file from my eclipse but it's still in my work space but I can't import it, also when I go to library and try to import it nothing appear,, all my projects get red x .please any help?

Comment: I'm not sure how it's called in Eclipse, but try invalidating cache and restarting. Also, do a gradle sync

Comment: I'm beginner in android eclipse , How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

try right clicking your project, go to Android Tools Fix project properties, and Add support libraries.

Comment: unfortunately,, nothing happen,

Comment: then create a new project from scratch as you did before and add appcompat to your project again.